# Electronic Check

Tags: contribution-page

We are using Authorize.net and on their site it says they accept electronic checks. How do I set up my Civi contribution page to accept both credit card and electronic check?

Comment: I see I have to create a separate payment processor for electronic check payments. I did that using Authorize.net credentials, but when I choose that option from my contribution page I just get the credit card entries, and not options to enter in check information. How do I get the check information to show up instead of the credit card entries?

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension that sets up the eCheck processor for AuthorizeNet. Once installed you should be able setup a separate processor for echecks.

More info in the link in KatinG's answer. This can be installed directly through CiviCRM (Administer>System Settings>Extensions Add New). We had a site using it under 4.6 with WordPress with no issues.

Hope this helps.

Comment: a link would make this answer more helpful

Comment: Just edited answer with install information.

Comment: I added the extension, but when I placed it in my contribution page I am getting this error Fatal error: Call to undefined method CRM_Core_Payment_AuthorizeNet::setBackOffice() in /home/aflbs/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/ProcessorForm.php on line 70    Does anyone know what I can do to fix this so I do not get this error?

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you using? There is a note on the extension page that says "WARNING: Does not work on 4.7.23+ because it overrides a core CiviCRM file".

Comment: Looking on GitHub it looks like the developer is not able to do any work on this extension.

Comment: I am using 4.7.22. So is the only answer to revert back to an older version of Civi? Or can someone help me get through that core payment error?

Answer (score 1):

The default Authorize.net payment processor that ships with CiviCRM Core does not have the ability to handle e-cheques; try install:

```
https://civicrm.org/extensions/authorizenet-echecknet
```

do give it a good test - on a development/staging environment (with a copy of your site) - as it does not look like many people are using it; `current usage: 8`